# Android Fade Out To New View

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio

I have an ImageView. When I change its image resource, I want to fade to the new resource. (I don't want the old resource to fade out and the new one to fade in; I want the new one to already be in the background and the old image to fade out, revealing the new image.) Is there a way to do this with only one View? I don't want to use two stacked Views because I need to do this with enough images that it would be bad for performance. Right now, I just have the basics:

fadeout animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

using fadeout animation on the View

```
Animation fadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
fadeout.setDuration(0);
boardView[location].startAnimation(fadeout);
```

Now, I need to somehow make the new image appear in the background as the View is fading out. Is this possible without adding a second View in the background?

Comment: u want to first fadeout first image and then want to fadein in second image??

Comment: No, I want the second image to already appear in the background as the first is fading out.

Comment: means want to both fadeout anb fadein at a time for two different image ..??

Comment: No, I don't want the second image to fade in. I want it to be behind the first image as it fades out.

Comment: Cant find a way you cant do this without having another imageview behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 1,0);
```

This would be the one of the way to do fade in/out animation. You just needs to the pass the view to which perform the animation, objectAnimator supports from honeycomb version

Comment: Others might benefit with a little explanation as to why this single line of code is a solution.